# Button not displaying in layout

Tags: android, button, layout

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logoLayout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/csr_logo2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"


        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotted_line" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/normal_line" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <com.example.sparsh.newcsraudit.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.example.sparsh.newcsraudit.CustomViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Complete Audit" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The 'Button' doesn't display in the layout.

My button needs to be displayed in every category of the layout.
Tried adding button to my activity that holds the categories, but it's not working.

Tried making adjustments, but didn't succeed.

Also, looked for similar questions online, but couldn't find the solution.

How do I make the button display in the layout.

Please help!

Comment: did you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Try this change your root Layout to **`RelativeLayout`** and make your `Button` `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

And make your

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/logoLayout"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/kid_goku" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/lineLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="2dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/ic_message"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView5"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/kid_goku" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         app:tabMode="scrollable" />

     <com.example.sparsh.newcsraudit.CustomViewPager
         android:id="@+id/pager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     </com.example.sparsh.newcsraudit.CustomViewPager>
 </LinearLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Complete Audit" />



</RelativeLayout>
```